# How to make this JavaScript code work in Opera

Tags: javascript, html-table, cross-browser, opera

The following code works on the latest version of Firefox, Chrome, Safari and IE but not on Opera. When I click on the add button using Opera, a very thin space seems to have been added to row, but nothing else... Can anyone help? 
The Form:

```
<form method="post" action="send.php">
<table id="table">
<tr><th>job</th><th>comment</th></tr>
<tr>
<td><textarea name = "job[]"></textarea></td>
<td><textarea name = "comment[]"></textarea></td>
<tr>
</table>
<input type ="button" value="add entry" onclick="add('table')"/>
<input type ="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/>
```

The JavaScript:

```
var names = ['job[]', 'comment[]'];

function add(tableID) {
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

for (var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    var newentry = document.createElement('textarea');
    newentry.type = "text";
    newcell.appendChild(newentry);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't test this, but you could try this: `newentry.style.height='20px';` before appending the `textarea` to the cell.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work...:(

Comment: If you inspect the table after running the code in Opera, does it contain the new row, cell and textarea? (You can use Dragonfly for this)

Comment: Hi Jani, by "inspect" did you mean looking into the source code? If so there is nothing there; on the other hand, if I check the source code on other browsers, I don't see the appended new row, cell etc. either, even though I can see new rows being created on the browser (as a user) and fill out the form. You probably meant something else; I'll download Dragonfly and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jani, turns out Dragonfly is built right in (thanks for the heads up!) It seems my code is actually OK; it was my if/else code that got messed up. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line: `newentry.type = "text";` causes an exception in Opera: `Uncaught exception: DOMException: NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR`. The line does nothing anyway (at least in Chrome), so I guess you can remove it.

```
var newentry = document.createElement('textarea');
newentry.type = "text";
console.log(newentry.type);
```

`-> textarea`

Answer (score 2):

Setting `newentry.type` gives

`Uncaught exception: DOMException: NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR`

Actually, there is not type attribute of `textarea`, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp. You would need the type if you would use `input`.

If you remove the line setting the type, it works good.

I also spotted another error in your code: you don't close the second row, but open a new one.

This is the good code:

`<tr>

<td><textarea name = "job[]"></textarea></td>

<td><textarea name = "comment[]"></textarea></td>

</tr>`

Comment: Thanks! kapsi suggested the same solution:)

Answer (score 0):

Use native DOM methods like `.createElement` to create TR(row) and TD(cells) which are supported across all browsers.

Your code might look as following:

```
var names = ['job[]', 'comment[]'];

function add(tableID) {
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.getElementsByTagName("TR").length;
var row = document.createElement("TR")
var colCount = table.getElementsByTagName("TR")[0].childNodes.length;

for (var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
    var newcell = document.createElement("TD");
    row.appendChild(newcell);
    var newentry = document.createElement('textarea');
    newentry.type = "text";
    newcell.appendChild(newentry);
    }
}
table.appendChild( row );
}
```

I didn't test the above code, but it will help you to get there.

Comment: Hi Epuri, thanks for the suggestion. I'm still a newbie in JavaScript. Would you mind showing me how I could use .createElement to create rows and cells?